# Why did the writers choose the names "Birch St." and "Higgins Dr."?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, behind-the-scenes, jessica-jones-2015

In *Jessica Jones*, we see Jessica chant a mantra consisting of the streets she grew up on: Birch Street, Higgins Drive, Cobalt Lane. Later, we learn that Birch and Higgins intersect at an important location.

Was there some reason for the writers to choose these specific street names? They seem important, having been the focus of many scenes or episodes. The sign posts were also in the trailer and intro, prime spots for references.

[image: Junction of Birch Street and Higgins Drive.]

I've [seen it suggested](https://www.quora.com/What-easter-eggs-were-in-Jessica-Jones-Season-1) that Cobalt Lane is a reference to [Cobalt Man](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Ralph_Roberts_(Earth-616)), but that seems loose.

Comment: A very quick search suggest that there's only one [Higgins Drive](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Higgins+Dr,+Stony+Point,+NY+10980/@41.2256657,-74.022794,17z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x89c2c4d111107309:0xf8f019a6b82da19b) in New York and it only intersects two roads, Thompson Crescent and Brainerd Drive.

Comment: @Richard All of New York or just the city?

Comment: Just the city. In the state there's a few more but none of them seem to intersect a Birch Street

Comment: W Higgins Lake Dr & W Birch Rd, Michigan,  is the closest I can find. Sounds intentionally fictional.